# How to track when a data download from SQL Server DB in Email

Tags: sql-server-2008, email, dbo

I am using SQL server email client.

I am sending mails using

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail                                                                           
    @profile_name = 'Mailer_Profile',    
    @recipients = @Email,      
    @copy_recipients = @ccRecipts,    
    @body = @MESSAGE  ,                                                                           
    @body_format = 'HTML',        
    @subject = @SUB
```

In the  @MESSAGE we are putting some information , when the mail will be opened , it has to be downloaded from our Database end. We need to track this. i.e. when it was downloaded or which mail ID it has downloaded.

Comment: -1, no clear objective. Clarify your question. How do you expect the callback to happen? You'll likely need an HTTP server of sorts to handle the request for the link, presenting the user the requested content while logging the request as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want know if the mail has been opened, or has the link been clicked and some data downloaded?

If the former is true, then there's no way to check this from sql server. Over here you can check `sent_status` field, which has three values for: 1=sent, 2=failed and 3=unsent. But no value for delivered.

```
SELECT * FROM msdb..sysmail_mailitems
```

If you want to check if the user has clicked the link, then your code `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` doesn't help much, because we don't know what is supposed to happen when the user clicks the link, and you'll have -10 for this question very soon :).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)